# CAS is Unavailable

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, cas

A general exception occurred while trying to access CAS. Please notify your system administrator.

I am new to this topic, so I started from basic.
I followed step by step process from the following site

https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/Demo

when I finished step-8, everything was fine and I got similar kind of logs as mentioned in step-8, when I hit this url

http://sathishkumar:8080/servlets-examples/servlet/HelloWorldExample

I am getting "CAS is Unavailable

A general exception occurred while trying to access CAS. Please notify your system administrator" error.

I created certificate with sathishkumar as Common Name(CN) because it my computer name.

I am running it in windows

Comment: Check logs to see the error.

Comment: There is no proper info in logs.